# How to place the subject line under the greeting line in t-letter module in ConTeXt?

Tags: context, letters

I'm writing a letter using the t-letter module available with ConTeXt.  I want the subject line to be underneath the greeting line, but I can't work out how to do it.

I think it is something like:

```
\setupletterstyle[subject][after=opening]
```

The relevant documentation is, I think, at page 55 here, but I still can't work it out: http://dl.contextgarden.net/modules/t-letter/doc/context/third/letter/correspondence.pdf

Comment: Since there has been no reply, you could try posting your question to the ConTeXt mailing list. Wolfgang Schuster, the author of the letter module, regularly reads the list.

Answer (score 1):

This is an ugly workaround to swap the opening and subject:

```
\setupletterstyle [opening]
    [
        before={\blank[-4*line, force]},
         after={\blank[4*line]},
    ]

\setupletterstyle [subject]
    [
        before={\blank[2*line, force]},
    ]
```